# How to get user id in Quickblox using the iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, quickblox

I am new to Quickblox and am interested in using the chat feature.
However it is required to send the id of the user to whom the current logged in user would like to chat. In the sample code, the id seemed to be hardcoded.
However i would like to get the id of the user from Quickblox. 
How do i get the user id of the logged in users to the application?

Thanks
Srinivasa Pradeep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample iOS chat http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-chat_users-ios

It shows exactly this case, how to work with Users+Chat

I can't post iOS code here because it's better and simplier to download src from github and play with it

Comment: I am unable to get user avatar in chat screen.How is possible??

Answer (score 1):

For the lazy, the relevant solution is the sample-users project:

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-ios-sdk/tree/master/sample-users

For the lazier, here is what I did in swift:

```
func loadUsersWithCompletion(completion: ((results: [QBUUser]?)->Void)) {
    let responsePage: QBGeneralResponsePage = QBGeneralResponsePage(currentPage: 0, perPage: 100)
    QBRequest.usersForPage(responsePage, successBlock: { (response, responsePage, users) in
        print("users received: \(users)")
        completion(results: users)

        }) { (response) in
            print("error with users response: \(response.error)")
    }
}
```

I'm slowly finding out that Quickblox has all the functionality I need, but a lot of the documentation simply refers to the sample projects and there's not much code available on SO. I suppose this forces you to look at actual code rather than copy pasta.

Comment: I am using method get users with ID and getting success but no user i.e blank user with response 200. Please help me if you can. Thanks